# Get minimum key and Integer of HashMap<T1, Set<T2>> with java 8 way

Tags: java, java-8

I know how to get minimum key and element from `HashMap<T, Double>`:

```
public static<T> Map.Entry<T, Double> getEntryOfMinimumVal(Map<T, Double> map) {
    return  map.entrySet().stream()
            .min(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Double::compareTo)).get();
}
```

But, I can not get the key and `Set` in `HashMap<T1, Set<T2>>` for the `Set` containing the minimum value:

```
/**
 * return minimum value of {getValue(elem)}_{elem is T2 values in all values of mapOfSet} 
 *   and key of type T1 whose value (Set<T2) contains the minimum value 
 */
public static<T1, T2> Map.Entry<T1, T2> getMinimumKeyAndElement(HashMap<T1, Set<T2>> mapOfSet){
    ???
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please read it again and improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not doing it in 2 steps:

1. find minimum value in all sets
2. find any map entry containing a set with this value

Because there might be no such value, you should use Optional as a return type.
And you should use wildcards in your parameter type, to provide a more flexible API:

```
public static<T1, T2> Optional<Map.Entry<T1, Set<T2>>> getMinimumKeyAndElement(Map<? extends T1,? extends Set<? extends T2>> mapOfSet){
   T2 minValue = mapOfSet.values().stream().flatMap(Set::stream).min(comparator_for T2);
   return mapOfSet.entrySet().stream().filter(s->s.getValue().contains(minValue)).findFirst();
}
```